# Варианты использования rails new --javascript и rails new --skip-javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails по-умолчанию устанавливает JQuery и CoffeeScript. Как быть, если я хочу отказаться от использования чего-либо из этого (всего)?

Первым делом пробил `rails new -h`, что выдало мне обширное количество флагов, доступных при создании нового проекта.

JavaScript'а там касается всего пара штук, а именно `rails new --javascript` и `rails new --skip-javascript`. Я предполагаю, что отключение JQuery и CoffeScript производятся именно там, потому что если просто удалить строчку `use 'jquery'` в Gemfile, то это ломает все приложение.

Интересуют также возможные варианты использования этих флагов. Что можно вообще прописать в `--javascript` кроме JQuery (и, повторюсь еще раз, что писать, чтобы вообще отключить использование какой-либо библиотеки)? Что будет при использовании флага `--skip-javascript`?

Comment: `use`? Может, `gem`?

Comment: @D-side да, конечно. Описка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете не знать о том, что там используется jQuery. Вы можете пользоваться им не напрямую, через jQuery-UJS (Unobtrusive JavaScript). Параметр `:remote`, ссылки не `GET`'ом, вот это всё. Если его убрать, некоторые вещи на страницах, к которым многие Rails-разработчики привыкли, перестанут работать.

Если сгенерить приложение с флагом `--skip=javascript`, приложение сгенерируется без JS-ассетов вообще. По неизвестным мне причинам (в Rails 4.2.6) остаётся `uglifier`, но поскольку он участвует лишь в сборке (а собирать нечего), эффект заметен не будет: а если вы всё же захотите что-то добавить, у вас сразу будет минификация. Хотя его можно безопасно убрать, если он вам не нужен.

При этом ничего не мешает убрать JS и из существующего проекта, если очень хочется:

- убрать соответствующие гемы
- убрать их `require` из манифестов Sprockets в ассетах
- убрать из вьюх код подключения
- если очень хочется, стереть релевантные пустые файлы

Если после отрезания какой-то "лишней детали" приложение взорвалось, выясните, почему — видимо, то, что вы отрезали, где-то всё же использовалось. Пользуйтесь контролем версий, чтобы не бояться делать потенциально опасные вещи.